# Dies oder dieses?

Tags: word-usage

Ich stoße immer wieder in den Dokumenten, die ich geschäftlich bearbeite, auf das Wort "dieses", wo ich aber immer einfach nur "dies" schreiben würde. Beispiel:

> XYZ wird vorläufig nicht umgesetzt. Dieses wird in der nächsten Version enthalten sein.

Das kommt mir spanisch vor. Dies würde für mich nur Sinn ergeben, wenn es beispielsweise hieße:

> Dieses [Feature] wird in der nächsten Version enthalten sein.

Noch seltsamer finde ich die Variante

> Dieses wird für die nächsten Version geschehen.

Dann bezieht sich das Wort klar nicht auf das Feature XYZ, sondern auf dessen Umsetzung. Aber dann würde ich erst recht nur "dies" schreiben.

Also, erstens: Ist "dies" überhaupt korrekt (manchmal habe ich das Gefühl, der einzige zu sein, der es verwendet)? Und ist "dieses" auch korrekt? Warum? Oder warum nicht?

Comment: Schön ist beides nicht. Warum nicht *es* oder *das*?

Comment: @Mrmfldmn: "Das" finde ich hier nicht passend: *Das wird in der nächsten Version enthalten sein*? Hmm, nö. Und "es" stellt aus meiner Sicht nicht die formelle Beziehung her, die man in einem offiziellen Dokument benötigt. Natürlich gibt es noch mehr Möglichkeiten, beispielsweise: "XYZ wird vorläufig nicht umgesetzt und daher erst in der nächsten Version enthalten sein". Aber darum ging es bei der Frage weniger :)

Comment: @Mrmfldmn Das ist Ansichtssache. Ich finde `dies` durchaus eleganter als `das`.

Comment: Meine Wahl wäre (wahrscheinlich, muss ich hinzufügen, denn es kommt natürlich auf das betreffende Feature und den Kontext an): *Es wird in der nächsten Version enthalten sein.* oder *Das wird in der nächsten Version geschehen.* Für meinen Geschmack wird *dies* oder *dieses* auch in offiziellen oder technischen Zusammenhängen zu häufig verwendet. Es macht einen Satz oft unnötig holprig, amtlich, distanziert. Aber, klar: Ansichtssache.

Comment: Naja, amtliches bzw. technisches Deutsch ist nicht aus Spaß so kompliziert. Es soll eindeutig sein. Dass dadurch mitunter holprige Konstellationen entstehen, halte ich für unausweichlich - am Ende werden schließlich keine Schönheitspreise vergeben. Ich stimme dir allerdings zu, natürlich kann man auch hier auf häufige Wiederholungen verzichten, um den Text insgesamt flüssiger zu gestalten.

Answer (score 13):

Der Link zu [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-dieser-jener3.html), den [bummi in seiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5783/dies-oder-dieses/5784#5784) verlinkt hat, sagt aus, dass die Verwendung von *dies* in dem von dir genannten Kontext die gewöhnlichere Variante ist.

> **dieses und dies**:
>
> Neben *dieses* kann im Nominativ und Akkusativ Neutrum auch *dies* stehen, vor allem dann, wenn das Pronomen nicht für ein Wort, sondern für eine Aussage steht:
>
> Sie haben ihm den Eintritt verweigert. Dies kann er nicht verstehen.
>
> selten: Sie haben ihm den Eintritt verweigert. Dieses kann er nicht verstehen.

Da in deinem Kontext das Pronomen ebenfalls eine Aussage ersetzt, ist also *dies* die gängige Variante, kann aber durch *dieses* durchaus ersetzt werden.

Comment: OK, das heißt dann wohl, dass ich *dieses* nur durch *dies* ersetze, wenn ich sowieso den ganzen Absatz überarbeite... ;)

Comment: @OregonGhost: Ich pflichte Em1 bei und vermute, dass wir es hier mit dem Phänomen zu tun haben, dass Leute, die sich unsicher sind, gerne zu umständlichen Formulierungen greifen in der Annahme, das sei guter Stil.

Comment: Ja, dieses glaube ich auch. Wenn das Dokument sehr alt wäre (so 18. oder 19. Jh.), könnte es auch eine durchaus übliche, obgleich gehobene Variante zu *dies* sein. So habe ich es nämlich schon öfter gelesen.

Answer (score 1):

Vielleicht auch interessant in diesem Zusammenhang:

​3. **unflektiertes dies**: Anstatt des Neutrums *dieses* wird häufig auch das unflektierte *dies* in gleicher Bedeutung gebraucht, vor allem wenn es allein stehend verwendet wird. Entscheidend für die Wahl ist der Satzrhythmus: *Ich wusste, dass es dies gab. Dies alberne Geschwätz widert mich an.*

(c) Duden ‒ Das Wörterbuch der sprachlichen Zweifelsfälle, 8. Aufl. Berlin 2016