# When is Dies better than Dieses?

Tags: demonstrative-pronoun

I have learned that *dies* is a contracted form of *dieses* in the singular Nominative or accusative Neuter. My question is, in which case is Dies preffered over Dieses and vice versa?

Thanks.

Comment: [Related question in German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5783/dies-oder-dieses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the two words mean the same and *can* widely be used interchangeably.

Having said this, *dieses* usually fits better when it refers to a countable thing and *one thing in particular*.

> Zum Thema Wörter: *dieses* paßt hier besser als dies.

*Dies*, on the other hand, fits better for uncountable (or, rather, non-countable) things: concepts, opinions and so on. Also for non-specified things:

> Er glaubte, zu gewinnen. *Dies* sollte sich als Irrtum herausstellen.

also

> *Dies* habe ich gefunden: ein Buch, ein Licht und ein Lesezeichen.

Here what was found is not specified at the time and hence "dies" is used. In contrast, in the following sentence we already know what is spoken about:

> Jenes Buch habe ich gekauft. *Dieses* habe ich gefunden.

You can also use "das" as a *Demonstrativpronomen* instead of *dies*. In German there is the proverbial "dies und das" with about the same meaning as "this and that" in English: "nothing in particular".

> Er glaubte, zu gewinnen. *Das* sollte sich als Irrtum herausstellen.

would be equally correct, grammatically as well as stylistically.